# What font is used for Batman: The Animated Series?

Tags: font-identification

Can somebody tell me what font the word "BATMAN" is in this image? Or what any very similar font style to that.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Plaza](http://www.fonts.com/font/itc/plaza/regular) - Next time you can use [whatthefont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/).

Comment: [Be kind, show a preview of the font please.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/be-kind-show-a-preview-of-the-font)

Answer (score 0):

The font type is called Andes and for some computers it's already installed by default.

http://www.dafont.com/search.php?q=andes

[image]

Comment: Neither my [Mac](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_macOS) nor my [Windows pc](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Microsoft_Windows) came with this font. Are you sure it's not a freebie from some other software?